# StreamWriter not writing to location other that exe location

Tags: streamwriter, streamwriter.write

This is my code broken down:

```
fileName = string.Concat("C:", @"\test.txt");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false);    
StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
row.AppendLine("Test");
sw.Write(row.ToString());
sw.Close();
```

This code does not generate a file, nor does it give an error.  If I change the first line to `filename = "test.txt";` then the program creates the file in the same location as the exe (bin/debug) and writes the text to it.  How can I get the program to write to a different path besides the path the exe is located in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write somewhere other than `C:\`. Windows does not allow non-admin users to write to the root of the C: drive, and your `string.Concat` sets a folder that tries to do so. Change it to a different folder than the root of the drive, and it should work fine.

(You should be using `Path.Combine` instead of `string.Concat` to build path and filenames, BTW. It properly handles adding path separators in the proper locations as needed.)